# Importing data from csv to Mysql using Yii Framework

Tags: yii

I need to import data from CSV file into MySql database using YII Framework,

CSV files contains datas which should to imported to two tables in Mysql DB, Please provide any information to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this
[Importing CSV file to mysql table using "LOAD DATA" command](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/336/importing-csv-file-to-mysql-table-using-load-data-command/)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this extension:

www.yiiframework.com/extension/importcsv/